# How to switch between view controllers and get rid of the previous one

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In android, switching between activities, is fairly straightforward

you call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class); <- define the next activity
startActivity(intent); <- start the next activity
finish(); < -get rid of the current activity
```

now in iOS i know how to do this:

```
UIViewController *nextviewcontroller = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextvc" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewcontroller:nextviewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How do I get rid of the current view controller? so that currentviewcontroller dies after presenting nextviewcontroller ?

[self dismissViewController:YES]; doesnt seem to do the trick

the lifecycle methods viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear are called even if I don't call `[self dismissViewController:YES];`

i want "`currentviewcontroller`" to be removed from the `memory`, and from the viewcontroller stack, so that clicking "back" in "nextviewcontroller" will go to some thirdviewcontroller that was before currentviewcontroller

Comment: describe the structure of your view controllers. are you using a navigation controller? why is this VC presented instead of pushed?

Comment: thirdviewcontroller->currentviewcontroller->nextviewcontroller->thirdviewcontroller->fourthviewcontroller

Comment: @LenaBru what did you end up doing I am on the same issue, basically want to get rid of the LoginController after the user logs in and not let him go back to it. Can you post what answer you ended up going with?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS is different, since there's no concept of Activity and everything is more focused on the app itself (in Android you can mix activities from different apps). Therefore, there's no concept of "view controller stack".
The most similar concept is the "navigation stack" of navigation controllers, where you actually push and pop new view controller into some kind of linear navigation. A navigation bar is automatically created and populated with back buttons.

presentViewController will show your view controller modally upon the current one, but you can't thrash the presenting one since it's holding and containing ("defining context") the new one.

If you use a navigation controller for your navigation hierarchy (I don't know if you can), you can override the back button and use something like

```
UIViewController * prev = self.navigationController.viewControllers[self.navigationController.viewControllers.count -2 ]
[self.navigationController popToViewController:prev animated:YES]
```

With a modal view controller, you may try something like (I haven't tried but it may work)

```
[self.presentingViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

You should write one of these code into the target action of your close button.

Comment: how do i find out if it was removed from the memory or not?

if i run nextviewcontroller alone, without any of the previous ones, it takes up 15-18 MB of memory. if i go through the previous ones , it goes up to 43MB of memory... how do i get rid of the previous ones from the memory ?

Comment: You can put logging in your controllers' `dealloc` methods to find out if they are being cleaned up properly.

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't maintain a global stack of controllers in the way that Android does.  Each app shows a controller at its root, and that one is responsible for showing the other controllers in the app.  Controllers can display other controllers modally using `presentViewcontroller:animated:completion:` but the presenting controller remains underneath the presented one.

If your current controller is the root controller, then instead of using `presentViewcontroller:animated:completion:` you'd just do this:

```
self.view.window.rootViewController = nextViewController;
```

It's very common for the root controller to be a `UINavigationController`, which does manage a stack of controllers.  If that is the case, and if your current controller is at the top of the stack, you'd do this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

If your setup is different, you'd do something different; it's hard to say what without knowing more.  But it's most likely that you'd be in the `UINavigationController` case.

Comment: i've tried changing the root view controller, but i want the upcoming view controller to be shown with animation, how do i do that then ?

Comment: The hard way is to do it with `[UIView transitionWithView:options:animations:completion:]`; you have to add the new controller's view (taking rotation into account yourself) inside the animation, then undo that and change the root view controller in the completion block.

The easy way is to put your controllers in a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

In the viewDidAppear of your nextviewcontroller you could add :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];    
    NSArray *controllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    NSMutableArray *newViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:controllers];
    [newViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:[controllers count]-2];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = newViewControllers;
}
```

Comment: may be add the moving code in the completion block better.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing available like this in iOS but you can achieve it doing something like below

```
NSArray *viewControllers=[self.navigationController viewControllers];

NSMutableArray *newControllers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=[viewControllers indexOfObject:self];i<viewControllers.count;i++){
        [newControllers addObject:[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i]];
}

[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:newControllers]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the method of storing all the view controllers in an array but it didn't work for me . When you try `popViewController` it will move to the View Controller which is last in the stack. 
You can make 2 navigation controllers and switch between them and also switch between the view controllers of a particular Navigation Controller.
For eg. 
You can switch between 2 Navigation Controller using the following code:

```
    FirstNavController *fisrtView=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstnavcontroller"];
        self.window.rootViewController = firstView;

    }else{
        SecondNavController *secondView=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginnavcontroller"];
        self.window.rootViewController = secondView;

    }
```

If your FirstNavController has 2 ViewControllers then you can switch between them using pushViewController

```
SecondViewController *sc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondviewcontroller"];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:sc animated:YES];
```

and popViewController

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```